# Does cardinality explode in Prometheus if two high cardinality metrics never vary together?

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

I have a Prometheus metric request_duration with a label "endpoint". A service is running, and being scraped, and is reporting metrics to prometheus for 100 different endpoints that are all being hit, e.g. `{endpoint="/users/"}` and 99 other endpoints. A new label is added, "user_id" (and there are 10,000 users), *but* "user_id" is only set on the `/users/` endpoint and not when the endpoint label is set to anything else.

Assume metrics are being reported to prometheus for all possible "user_id" and "endpoint" label values (but "user_id" will only vary for a single endpoint, `/users/`, and be unset for all other endpoints)

Is there potential for a "cardinality explosion" here that would cause memory issues if more high-cardinality labels were added? Is a cardinality explosion in Prometheus based on a potential number of label combinations (100 * 10,000) or an actual number of label combinations (99*1 + 1*10,000)?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that for every distinct labelset metric is stored as a separate time series.

Prometheus will not create labelsets of `{endpoint="/", user_id="1"}` if they aren't exposed, same as it would not create labelset `{endpoint="/foo/"}`.
So you second estimation of (99*1 + 1*10,000) is correct one.

On the other hand, what you are doing feels more like it belongs to logs (or traces), and not metrics. Especially since number of users is usually not that stable metric, and sudden grow of that number might occur at any time. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46376906/21363224) by @brian-brazil (author of robustperception.io).